# Column that assigns 0 or 1 if value is correct or not

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am trying to create a column that assigns 0 or 1 if two pieces of data match. So

```
TrueLocation     PerfectLocation      PassOrFail
NY                    Boston              0
Boston                 Boston             1
```

My go ahead was not great...

```
SELECT *, COUNT (TrueLocation) / COUNT(PerfectLocation) as PassOrFail
FROM Table1;
```

This doesn't work, and I see why. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have two different Databases tagged here. Is this Microsoft Access or Oracle's Mysql? They would use slightly different functions to achieve this (`iif` vs `if`/`case`).

Comment: I am currently using MS Access, but I can switch to MySql no problem if Access doesn't handle the code properly.

Comment: Both are equally suited for this one. Access would use `iif()`, Mysql would use `if()` or a `CASE` expression and every other RDBMS under the sun would just use a `CASE` expression. I've added the answer for Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Access you can use the `iif()` function. This would look like:

```
SELECT *, iif(TrueLocation = PerfectLocation, 1, 0)
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Interesting..that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, since boolean values in MS Access are represented using the integers `-1` & `0`, you can also use the following to yield the same result (albeit not as readable):

```
select *, -(TrueLocation = PerfectLocation)
from Table1
```